Unable to record audio in GCP debian VM
I have been stuck to record audio in a debian vitual machine. uname -a gives: configuration is - 5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.221-1 (2024-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have installed pulse audio, pavucontrol, alsa(all installations), sox.
Have tried the folowing solutions-

With aplay -l, it displays no sound cards are available. I followed the solution on this link-https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082472/how-can-i-resolve-this-problem-unable-to-locate-package-linux-image-extra-4-15 . But on running this command-sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual i get error- E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64' E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-virtual

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434488/modprobe-fatal-module-snd-aloop-not-found-linstall-inux-modules-extra-5-4-0 sudo modprobe snd-gives-modprobe: FATAL: Module snd not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64 on running- sudo apt install linux-generic i get-E: Unable to locate package linux-generic

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install pulseaudio autospawn = yes


-on trying any pulse audio command- i get connection refused error.
The issue still remains unresolved. Please let me know if there is any possible solution. Thanks in advance.
